# Show min/max values with corresponding steps in TensorBoard scalar plots

Tags: tensorboard

I'm wondering if there's a tool/workaround to show min/max values on scalar plots in TensorBoard.
A pretty common scenario considers zooming in and finding the optimal point manually for each series, as it is not necessarily the last one.
For example, it is epoch 22 with `IoU=75.08` (the maximum value) for the grey series below.

[image]

I'd like to have these numbers displayed somewhere (for example in the tooltip or in the chart) or at least a marker in the optimal point.

I've found [an open ticket](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorboard/issues/1030) relating to this issue, but it seems that it is still not resolved.
Maybe someone is aware of some sort of a frontend script/plugin extracting these values? Preferably for Safari or Chrome.